# Where can I find the article of Kleiman: "Algebraic cycles and Weil conjectures. Dix exposés sur la cohomologie des schémas"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

Where on the Internet can I find the article of Kleiman: "Algebraic cycles and Weil conjectures. Dix exposés sur la cohomologie des schémas" ?

Comment: N.B. I had posted an answer with the following link: https://web.archive.org/web/20090126215449/http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~leila/grothendieckcircle/DixExp.pdf but Benjamin Dickman pointed out that it does not contain Kleiman's article.

Comment: See also https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/Fourothers.pdf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the bad news is that this book "Dix exposés sur la cohomologie des schémas" is still under copyright with Elsevier (inherited from North-Holland), which is why you will not find it legally on the internet (it's volume 3 of their "Advanced studies in pure mathematics"); the Grothendieck circle only scanned the chapters in this book by Grothendieck, omitting chapters 1,2,7, and 10 by others (this was intentional).

the good news is that many libraries have it, see http://www.worldcat.org/title/dix-exposes-sur-la-cohomologie-des-schemas/oclc/250067922